# Python: Getting largest n-digit number

Tags: python

Very stupid question but how can I quickly get the largest n-digit number with python? It's clear that number will always be n-occurrences of 9. So n=1 -> 9, n=2 -> 99 etc.

What I have is this:

```
max_str = ''
# there should be a better way to do this, right?
for i in range(self.number_length):
    max_str += '9'
max_value = int(max_str)
```

This works. But as the comment says, there must be a better way, right?

EDIT:

I made a quick and dirty performance comparison of the different options:

```py
%%timeit
10**5 - 1
```

```
8.97 ns ± 0.0952 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit
pow(10,5)-1
```

```
305 ns ± 1.13 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit
int("9" * 5)
```

```
137 ns ± 0.321 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit
max_str = ''
for i in range(5):
    max_str += '9'
```

```
401 ns ± 1.63 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

10**n - 1 for some reason is by far the fastest solution while pow(10,n) -1 isn't much faster than my loop approach.

Comment: `int("9" * self.number_length)` or `10 ** self.number_length - 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
10**n - 1
```

where `n` is the desired number of digits.

Comment: Selecting this as it seems to be by far the fastest option

Answer (score 0):

```
n_largest_number=pow(10,n)-1
```

Explanation: pow(a,b) function outputs a^b.